# opscenter "services" tab greyed out

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

Was hoping to set up an s3 snapshot with my cassandra cluster running opscenter 5.2.4/Cassandra 2.2.7 but for some reason the services menu is greyed out. Cluster stats and information seem fine so it can at least connect to all my nodes. Anyone know how to enable this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

OpsCenter 5.2.4 only supported up to DSE 4.8, which was C* 2.1. Cassandra 2.2 and 3.0 wont work well with it. Also mostly everything in the services tab is for enterprise users and relies on DSE features.